# POST values are lost with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`GET` values are OK.
This is my `.htaccess` rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

App is built using php codeigniter.
How can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue using R=307

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,L]
```